# Bootstrap Carousel Won't Load

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I didn't want my first question here to be something so simple, but I've spent a good 1-2 hours trying to figure this out and snooping around SO. I know the answer is likely  to be very simple, but I simply cannot find it. Anybody's help would be greatly appreciated:

```
<section class="content">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">…</div>
        <div class="item">…</div>
        <div class="item">…</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>

<article class="">

</article>
</section>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#myCarousel').carousel();
</script>
```

Edit: The issue! The Bootstrap Carousel loads just the elements statically onto the page. They're not working at all. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you including the Bootstrap CSS file?  See edit to my answer below with jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you're missing a `>` on your first list item:

`<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"</li>`

should be

`<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>`

#### Edit

Are you including the Bootstrap CSS file?

Everything appears to be working for me with the above change:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89Q3F/)